# VBA Error Handling RESUME

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

I have a piece of code that reads information from a table and inserts it into a table with a primary key. The first table is user entered by many different people and the second is the table i wish to clean up

To give you an idea of what happens the pseudo code below should help

1. Record is read into an array
2. Record is then inserted into a table with a primary key on a unique identifier from the array
3. If the unique identifier already exists in the table an error is thrown by the database (Not an Access Database)
4. The error message is trapped with the record that was attempted to be inserted. The offending record is now placed into an error table for later review
5. Resume where the error message was thrown

The problem is that the code resumes where the query was executed as opposed to at the start of the loop again in this case at line Set **rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()**
In practical terms what this means it is forever trying to insert the same record

In my error handler, i increment the loop on by one record so it now attempts to insert the next record. Unfortunately, that isn't considered on the resume next

What i would want in practice is that the loop is incremented by 1 in the error handler and then the loop attempts to insert the next record

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
intNumberRows = UBound(myArray, 2) + 1 ' number of records/rows in the array
rowcounter = 0


' Append the Rows of local Table to the temp table
For rowcounter = rowcounter To intNumberRows - 1

' Values X Y Z in this case records contained with the array being looped and inserted
    AppendQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(X,Z etc....)
    cmdSQLData.CommandText = AppendQuery
    cmdSQLData.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 60
    Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()

Next
```

**PSEUDO ERROR HANDLING CODE**

```
ErrorHandler:
If (Len(Err.Description) > 0) Then
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End If

Debug.Print Err.Number
Debug.Print AppendQuery

' Create Error Table For Upload and resume Inserting of records

If (Err.Number = -2147217900) Then
    runfunc = CreateErrorTable(variables)

    If runfunc = True Then
        rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
    Else:
        GoTo EndFunction
    End If
End If

EndFunction:
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmdSQLData = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rule of thumb. Never increment a For Next control variable. Only the loop should ever increment it. When I expect an error or when I'm generating an error as part of the business logic, I handle that error in the body of the code.

```
Sub InsertRows()

    Dim rowcounter As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    For rowcounter = 1 To 10
        On Error Resume Next
            'Execute query
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        If Err.Number = -2147217900 Then
            'Append to error table
        ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
           Err.Raise Err.Number 'reraise error outside of 'resume next'
        End If
    Next rowcounter

ErrorHandler:
    'handle other errors

End Sub
```

To me, the ErrorHandler is for unexpected errors. You're actually using this error in the logic to determine if the row already exists. If you expect that the row should never already exist, then kick it down to the error handler and abort the code. But if you expect that sometimes the row will already exist and the most efficient way for you to determine that is by trying to insert the row, then that error should be handled by you in the body of the code. That's my opinion at least.

Comment: Hi Dick, thank you for your advice its very much appreciated. I have a small question in relation to the error handling in the code. When exactly will the Resume Next be executed? Does it over ride the ErrorHandler?

Comment: The `On Error Resume Next` line is executed when the program gets to that line (or maybe I don't get the question). `On Error Resume Next` *is* the error handler. Any error encountered after `Resume Next` will essentially be ignored. Then once `GoTo ErrorHandler` is reached, any error will be redirected to that ErrorHandler label. There are basically three types of error handling `GoTo Label`, `Resume Next`, and `Goto 0`. The last one turns off error handling and any error will halt program execution.

Comment: Hi Dick...I have added the code the resume seems to supersede the GoTo ErrorHandler so when i get a second ID which is the same it resumes but it completely ignores the If Err.Number = -2147217900 segment of the code. I debug.print and the error code and the number is correct, just not being picked up by the If statement

Comment: Are you saying that the error number is -2147217900 but the If statement is returning False? Does the Err.Number <> 0 then return true? Make sure you've typed the error number correctly in the code.